# Importing python module from another ROS package setup.py

Tags: rospy, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am trying to import a python module from another ROS package.

```
My package is utils 
utils
-----/src
------------file_io.py (python module) 
------------__init__.py
```

I have a node in Package A that wants to import a function in file_io.py

So far I have created a setup.py file for the package utils

```
    ## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['utils'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    requires=['roscpp', 'rospy', 'tf']
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

In my cmakeList file I made the following changes

```
install(PROGRAMS src/file_io.py
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

and uncommented #catkin_python_setup()

In the package.xml of package A, I made the utils package a build and run dependency, modified the cmakList of package A and added the package utils to the find_package(catkin required COMPONENTS).

from utils.file_io import extractor
results in the import error: No module name file_io.

Am I missing something? To be honest I did not really understand the tutorial, I am kind of new to python.

As I understand in order to import a python module it has to be in your python path, I thought this setup thing was meant to make ROS automatically add the files to the python path of any package that depends on utils...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147391/importing-python-module-from-another-ros-package-setup.py/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no experience with this myself, but from the catkin documentation, it seems that if you want to only install the module utils, your should remove the

```
install(PROGRAMS src/file_io.py
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

from your `CMakeLists.txt` and move the two python files in `src` into another subfolder `utils`. Not sure if you need the `requires` in the `setup.py`.

I suggest to read the following page, in particular the "Modules" section carefully: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/installing_python.html

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2014-04-02**:
thanks the modules import works now. In the Rospy tutorial it installs a python executable using the setup.py even though the catkin documentation mentions not to at the end... And also you do not need the 'requires' in setup.py

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2016-12-28**:
Link is broken. Here is an updated [link](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html)